# Index over a set, I get two sets and not one

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, unions

I thought the following code would work the way I expcted.

```
p1 = [
    ({1}, (0,0)),
    ({2}, (0,0)),
    ({3},(0,0),
]
p2 = [
    ({1,2}, (1,0)),
    ({3}, (0,0)),
]
for k in range(len(p1)):
    m = set()
    for l in range(len(p2)):
        if p1[k] != p2[l]:
           m = m.union(
               set([min(p1[k][0])]))
    print(m)
```

What I should be getting is `{1,2}`, but I get

```
Set([1])
Set([2])
```

I also get an error message saying:

```
'set' object does not support indexing
```

and I don't know if I should be using some other command.

I am real grateful for any help I can get. I have thought about it for some time and have not been able to fix this.

Comment: Move `m = set()` and the `print(m)` outside of the for loop.

Comment: That will not solve the fact `set` does not support indexing. It is unclear how you want to merge the sets, please provide a brief explanation.

Comment: Correct, the issue with set not support indexing is because of the last entry in `p1` - `({3})` is not a tuple, so will `p1[2][0]` will throw an error. Presumably this should be a tuple, e.g. `({3}, )` which would fix the error.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not note that I made that change there, but yes, thats why I couldn't find the error in the code.. Sorry

Comment: Your tuple correction is missing a closing paren

Comment: @StivenG if you fix your code in the question, then your question is not longer valid. What you have should no longer provide the error described.

Comment: Please don't iterate over the range of indices of lists just to fetch their elements! Instead of ``for k in range(len(p1)):`` and then ``p1[k]`` simply do ``for element in p1:``. This is more robust, supports more types and is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to do, but just fixing your errors does not return you expected output. Using `itertools.product()` instead of nested for loops:

```
p1=[({1}, (0,0)), ({2}, (0,0)), ({3}, (0,0))]
#                                  ^^^^ a tuple now
p2=[({1,2}, (1,0)), ({3}, (0,0))]

In []
import itertools as it

m = set()
for k, l in it.product(p1, p2):
    if k != l:
        m.add(min(k[0]))
print(m)

Out[]:
{1, 2, 3}
```

Making a big assumption but if you meant to go through these lists both at the same time you would use `zip(p1, p2)`, e.g.:

```
In []:
m = set()
for k, l in zip(p1, p2):
    if k != l:
        m.add(min(k[0]))
print(m)

Out []:
{1, 2}
```